# Basic arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic

I can't understand how: $$ \frac {2\times{^nC_2}}{5} $$

Equals:

$$ 2\times \frac  {^nC_2}{5} $$

If we forget the combination and replace it with a $10$, the result is clearly different. $1$ in the first example and and $0.5$ in the second.

Comment: $\dfrac{2\times10}{5}=4$ and $2\times\dfrac{10}5=4$.  It is not clear how you got $1$ or $0.5$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: What does the notation ${}^n C_2$ mean? Is that the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{2}$ ("$n$ choose 2")?

Comment: Forget that Michael, silly mistake from me.

Comment: Daniel, in Portugal we learn to write combinations that way. I didn't know it could also be represented that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember some fact about fractions: $\dfrac{a}{b}\times \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{ac}{bd} \Rightarrow \dfrac{2\times \binom{n}{2}}{5} = \dfrac{2\times \binom{n}{2}}{1\times 5} = \dfrac{2}{1}\times \dfrac{\binom{n}{2}}{5} = 2\times \dfrac{\binom{n}{2}}{5}$

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{a}{b}\times\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a\times c}{b \times d}$$
So, taking your example
$$\frac{2\times10}{5\times 1}=\dfrac{2}{5}\times\dfrac{10}{1}=\dfrac{2}{1}\times\frac{10}{5}=\dfrac{10}{5}\times 2=\dfrac{2}{5}\times 10$$
As multiplication is commutative.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using your example,
$$ \frac{2\times 10}{5}=\frac{20}{5}=4$$
And 
$$ 2\times\frac{10}{5}=2\times 2=4$$
In general for any $c\not =0$, we have
$$ \frac{a\times b}{c}=a\times\frac{b}{c}= b\times\frac{a}{c} $$